# Javascript thead DOM overwrites first line of data

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm building a table dynamically and when I insert the header one of the results is missing.  It should be:

```
| header 1 | header 2 |
| data | data |
| data | data |
```

But is appearing as:

```
| header 1 | header 2 |
| data | data |
```

If I remove the `thead` part everything displays correctly.

Part of the code.

```
    for (var i = gymLinks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      //capture URL
      var url = gymLinks[i].substr(0, 106);
      //capture app version
      var appVersion = gymLinks[i].substr(108, 111);
      //Creating the table
      var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
      //create table header 
      var theader = table.createTHead (0);
      theader.innerHTML = '<tr><th>Gym Link</th><th>Version</th></tr>';              
      var row = table.insertRow(1);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      //creating table elements
      linkElement = document.createElement("a");
      linkElement.setAttribute("href", url);
      var linkText = document.createTextNode(url);
      //linkElement.append(linkText);
      cell1.innerHTML = '<a href="' + url + '">' + linkElement + "</a>";
      cell2.innerHTML = appVersion;
    }
  });
```

Comment: All of your code is inside a loop. you are overwriting everything every time the loop iterates. you need to rethink this whole thing.

Comment: Create the table and header *outside* the loop.

Comment: Move the thead bit outside of the loop. I would also move `var table = document.getElementById("myTable");` outside of the loop. You don't need to be searching through DOM every iteration.

Comment: change `table.insertRow(1)` to `table.insertRow(-1)` so it always appends

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. I don't think the loop is the issue.  Everything works fine without `thead` portion.  Also the loop is needed as I am parsing out a JSON response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is likely because you're only inserting rows into the same row index.

`var row = table.insertRow(1);`

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help you?

chance

```
for (var i = gymLinks.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

to

```
for (var i = 0 ; i <= gymLinks.length - 1; i++)
```

and try...

```
  var row = table.insertRow(i); or i+1??
```

Comment: `for (var i = gymLinks.length; i--;)` is all you need ot iterate backwards

Comment: and what about  
 var row = table.insertRow(i); or i+1   ??

Comment: the `+1` should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Amy and frobinsonj a combination of what they suggested did it.

I moved this to outside of the loop

```
    var theader = table.createTHead (0);
    theader.innerHTML = '<tr><th>Gym Link</th><th>Version</th></tr>';
```

Updated:

```
      var row = table.insertRow(1);
```